# Problem with $A.M.\geq G.M.$ Inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Question:**

> If $x^2+y^2=1$, prove that $-{\sqrt2}\leq x+y \leq\sqrt2$

**My approach:**
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\geq\sqrt{x^2y^2}$$
$$ \frac12\geq xy$$
$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\leq\sqrt{xy}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $$
Now how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Can you prove $(x+y)^2\le2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceeding from your approach, you had
$$2xy \leq 1$$
Adding $x^2 + y^2$ to both sides,
$$\implies x^2+2xy+y^2 \leq 1 + x^2 + y^2$$
$$\implies (x+y)^2 \leq 1 + 1$$
And you're done.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cauchy-Schwarz_Inequality) inequality we have
$$(x+y)^2 \leqslant (1+1)(x^2+y^2) = 2(x^2+y^2) = 2.$$
So $$|x+y| \leqslant \sqrt{2},$$ or $$ -\sqrt 2  \leqslant x + y \leqslant \sqrt 2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way: set $x=\cos\theta, y = \sin\theta,$ then
$$
x+y=\cos\theta+\sin\theta=\sqrt{2}\cos(\theta-\pi/4)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using  [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity) or directly

$$(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2=(1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2)$$

$$2(x^2+y^2)-(x+y)^2=\cdots\ge0$$

Answer (score 2):

Use $T_2$'s lemma to get,
$$1=x^2+y^2\geq \frac{(x+y)^2}{2}$$

Comment: just wondering, does T2's lemma proof use AM-GM ?

Comment: @Raheel It's basically a corollary of CS inequality. $T_2$'s lemma can be further generalized by holder and power mean inequality. If $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_n$ are positive reals, then$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i^p}{b_i^q}\geq n^{q+1-p}\frac{(a_1+\cdots +a_n)^p}{(b_1+\cdots+b_n)^q}$$whenever $p>q>0$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2=1\\(x+y) ^2=1+2xy\tag{1}$$ Now, you've got that $$\frac{1}{2}\ge xy\\ \frac{1}{2}\ge \frac{(x+y) ^2-1}{2}\tag{from (1)}\\ (x+y) ^2\le 2\\ -\sqrt 2\le x+y\le \sqrt 2$$